# Not sending a fetch file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch this:

```
fetch("https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=MYKEY&filename=teste", {
    body: "@/C:/Users/Acer/Pictures/1 (2).jpg",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
    },
    method: "POST",
});
```

But it does not work.

I am trying to submit a file from a `input` in my form.

Try this code in javascript:

```
<input accept="image/*" type="file" id="imgInp" />;

var input = document.getElementById("imgInp");

var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", input.files[0]);
data.append("user", "hubot");

fetch("https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=MYKEY", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
    },
    body: data,
});
```

PS.: In postman it works! Any idea?

Comment: [But not works](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem.

Comment: Odds are that if you bothered to open the Console and quote any errors you got this would turn out to be yet another duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068 though.

Comment: Sorry guys. The file is not submitted

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('imgInp');

var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', input.files[0])
data.append('user', 'hubot')

fetch('https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=MYKEY', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

You needs to omit `content-type` header for the on this request. The browser will automatically add the Content type header.

Comment: Tks for reply MD.RAKIB HASAN, but I get 200 response but without the file...
Note: I have about 10 input fields on the page. The querySelector is better that getElementById?

Comment: @LucasBersanoMatteo your can use ```getElementById``` .

Comment: Still not working.

The file stak requirementes are this:

fetch("https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=MyKey&filename=teste1", {
  body: "@/C:/Users/Acer/Pictures/1 (2).jpg",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "image/png"
  },
  method: "POST"
})

Any idea?